# Injection, Surjection and Bijection in

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, self-learning

I came across this claimed theorem:

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite-dimensional vector-spaces of equal dimension.
Let $L: V \rightarrow W $ be a linear function.

Then the following statements are equivalent:

- $L$ is injective
- $L$ is surjective
- $L$ is a bijection

Can someone give me a short summary why this is ?

Comment: What do you mean with `I suspect that L is a "bijective" morphism`? They assert  $L$ is a bijection.

Comment: sorry I dont know why I wrote that, I edited my post

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Use the rank-nullity formula and remember ‘$L$ injective’ is equivalent to ‘$\ker L=\{0\}$’, ‘$L$ surjective’ is equivalent to ‘$\dim (\operatorname{Im}L)=\dim W$’.

Comment: can I get a stronger hint, please ?

Comment: I've added some more hints.